# Why is header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); not working with multiple Ajax CALL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-redirect

I have multiple Ajax calls like

```
(async function(){
  await $.ajax({
          ...
  });
 ... next Ajax call 
 ...
})();
```

They working fine when i call them from a previous page and land on the scripting Ajax handler site.

But i want that the user dont get shown this page, so i tryed to add

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

that the user get directed to the source page where he submitted.

Maybe Problems with the await async? I have no alerts or something on the Ajax call Page its just a blank site.

thx for help.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is only set by browsers when following a link, and not always then. You can't rely on it being accurate, or even present in anything you might want to do.

Comment: Try add a header with referer in ajax request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798706/set-referer-url-with-ajax-request/16065622

Comment: @CoursesWeb `var referrer = "prev_page.php";` and adding  `headers: {'X-Alt-Referer': referrer },` to the ajax



not working i still end up on the Ajax handler php page