# Using $.getscript("") without sending referer header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using `$.getscript("");` to get remote script. However, when I use it, the referer information goes to there. I don't want to send the referer information when I use the function. Tried this without any luck,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { "Referer": "" }
});

$.getScript("http://www.example.org/script.js");
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The browser will overwrite the referrer always for the tests that I've done. Meaning you can't change the referrer of an ajax call.

Since `getscript()` is documented as being shorthand for an ajax call, this also applied to `getscript()`.

See:

[changing the referrer of an Ajax POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231366/changing-the-referrer-of-an-ajax-post)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending a request from a non-secure source to a secure source (http to https) the browser should *not* send the referer with the request. That is only a workaround though and it depends how well the browser follows through with web standards.

Comment: Its from http to http

Comment: If the source of the javascript file supports SSL/TLS (https) then try using that instead. The referer header should not be sent.

Comment: So you mean If I run the getscript function on a https site to http site, it wont send referer, correct ?

Comment: @user198989 actually i'm mistaken, sorry about that. The request had to be sent from https to http not the other way around. Sorry about that. You've got it right though, so yes that's correct.