# 403 Forbidden Error when I click on the link.Works Fine when enter the url in browser directly

Tags: java, http, tomcat, web-applications, http-status-code-403

I have a problem with opening site through the link in tomcat - I am got forbidden.

My steps are:
1. Launch http://hostname
2. Select https://hostname/Site
3. 403 forbidden message
When I am going directly through the browser like this https://hostame/site everything works fine.

even 
 Select https://hostname/OtherSite
 Works fine

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that you are not configured https in tomcat properly. Can you post configuration? From your test we can't help to fix.

Comment: You maybe use `POST link`, When you enter link in browser's address bar, this is `GET link`. Let check this.

Comment: @BoskoMijin for other linnk its working fine.

Comment: @DoNhuVy both are get request..... I checked in network

Comment: Yes, but as you can see: you are getting OK on https (different port than http). My intention is that you are not configured tomcat well, but I can't say what because I don't have the info about that. Check in configuration.

Comment: same problem, have you figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

here is my case.

you original page (with link) and the targeted linked page are not the same domain.

original-domain and target-domain.

if your target-domain not allow across-origin, then you get 403 forbidden error.

click link and enter url sending different request,

I found the difference is in request header:

click link (with 403 forbidden error),

```
         request header have one line:
                        Referer: http://original-domain/json2tree/ipfs/ipfsList.html
```

when I enter url, (no 403 forbidden),
                          the request header does NOT have above line referer: original-domain

I finally figure out how to fix this error!!!

on your original-domain web page, you have to add

```
              <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

it will remove or prevent sending the Referer in header,  works both for links and for Ajax requests made

Comment: this is how you remove referer in quest header https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817595/remove-http-referer