# How to put rel no referrer attribute on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, rel

I'm trying to add the rel no referrer attribute on JavaScript but it doesn't work. Here is what I tried:

```
DisableExitTraffic();
                        window.location = ('http://X.com"rel="noreferrer');});},10000);});},8500); }});};</script>
```

Comment: You may want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817595/remove-http-referer).

Comment: That's not what i'm talking about. I need the rel no referrer to be attached with the link!