# Prevent Link from Sending Referrer

Tags: html, web

How can I created an HTML meta refresh redirect that prevents the destination from discovering the originating URL? Thus, if I have my link forward to "google.com". "google.com" won't know that the link originated from "example.com/forward.html"?

Trying to get something like this to work:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://google.com' rel="noreferrer" " />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove http referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817595/remove-http-referer)