# Unable to get image url in Mangaeden API Angular 6

Tags: angular, rest, api, http-headers, cross-domain

I have tried to get the information of the Mangaeden API and I have successfully get a response but when I rendered the image from the url. I got an error 403. It seems there is a problem in requesting in the API.

This is the error in the application.

> GET
>   https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/63/63df51e43ebfb8983eb39744496b27ef6173b2237535b9c2408ea32d.jpg
>   403

But when I tried to load the url in the browser and the next time I try it on my application, It works because I think it will cache the image in the browser.

This is the Mangaeden API Information

> You can get all manga informations, chapters and mymanga with
>   mangaeden's API.  All the informations are sent in JSON format.  You
>   can either use HTTP or HTTPS (advised if you need to use the mymanga's
>   API).  Important: we require every API user to have a link to our site
>   in their application/site.  New: We also support CORS now

About this. Where can I add their link

> We require every API user to have a link to our site in their
>   application/site.

HTML

```
<img src="{{url}}">
```

Code for component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  url: String;

  constructor(private mangaedenService: MangaedenService) {}

  isRedered(id) {
    this.url = null;

    this.mangaedenService.getInfo(id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.url = 'https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/' + data.image;
      });
  }
}
```

Code for service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}) 
export class MangaedenService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getInfo(id) {
    return this.http.get('https://www.mangaeden.com/api/manga/' + id)
      .map(this.extract);
  }

  private extract(res: Response | any) {
    return res || {};
  }
}
```

Comment: In `MangaedenService` how exactly are you able to call `map` on `http.get` in the first place? If you're using Angular 6 shouldn't you call `pipe` on `get` and then pass `map` inside it? Also, I don't really see a need for this `map` in here. Finally, could you please create a sample stackblitz replicating this issue?

Comment: When I added this one `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` **Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no problem in my code. I got error when rendering images in html which got 403 response. I added this in my html code and It works.

`<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"/>`

You can also check this out

[Remove http referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817595/remove-http-referer)