# Reidrect to another page Using Fake referer

Tags: php, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Changing referer with header()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616977/php-changing-referer-with-header)

I have a website (www.king370.co.cc) on which I want to host a script. The visitors of that script should be redirected to (king370.blogspot.com). So far it can be done using Meta-Refresh or php headers. If I use Meta-Refresh then the stats of blogger show that there was a visit from www.king370.co.cc which is called the referrer URL. I want to change that Referrer URL before the redirect. So here I explain the complete flow of my application.

User Visits http://www.king370.co.cc/hello.php
in hello.php file I have written a meta-refresh tag so the page redirects to http://king370.blogspot.com
In the blogger stats, 'http://www.king370.co.cc/hello.php', is shown as the referral URL.
I want that referral URL to be changed to some other domain like 'www.somedomain.com'

The solution in any client-side or server-side technology is acceptable.

Comment: You can't influence that. It's a client-generated value.

Comment: May I ask for what purpose do you want to fake the referrer? Sounds like affiliate spoofing.

Comment: Nobody have come up with the solutions and just voting down my question.

@mario I know that its a client generated value. Is there no client-side solution for this purpose? This question is not duplicate of the question you linked. That question is changing referrer in header while my question is to change the referrer on client side.

Comment: @KaiMattern, I want the www.somedomain.com website to be famous and for that purpose I can set the referrer of every visit from my website (www.king370.co.cc) to www.somedomain.com so the backlinks to that site will increase the popularity of somedomain.com....

Comment: There are other duplicate questions pertaining to client-side workarounds in Javascript. Go forth and google them. If you come up with a solution yourself, post it here, get upvotes. Until then the recurring duplicates remain evidence that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it using a script. What your really want is your blog hosted on your domain instead of blogger's domain.  You can find out how to do that here: http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs

Comment: No. That's not my question. I want the referrer changed while redirecting to blog.pucitforums.co.cc or king370.blogspot.com