# PHP Set user's http referer

Tags: http, web

User John comes to site B from site A. The http referer in B says me that John came from A. Now John comes back to A. The http referer in A says John came from B.

Now my question is:

My website is B and is developed in php. I have no access to site A. How can i change John's http referer so when he goes to site A from my site B, site A sees http referer website C instead of website B?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Changing referer with header()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616977/php-changing-referer-with-header)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no access to site C it is impossible.