# How to set custom http referer in PHP

Tags: php, http, url

Hi I need a php script for spoof http referer, If some one open any one of the link on my web page that should not show my url. It should show some another url like "http://exampledomain.com/page1.php". I've seen some of the fake referer in my statcounter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide Referrer on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428762/hide-referrer-on-click)

Comment: This way called Cross-site scripting (XSS), You can use `iframe` where you can view the content of website where you are in another website

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, the browser sets the referrer.

You can use an anonymyzer service to link to, known as a "dereferrer", so links from your site take another 'hop', hiding your site.