# What is the most reliable way to empty users' HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: javascript, php, http-referer

I have a page that redirects users to another website via PHP's header() function. However, I want to empty the HTTP_REFERER variables of users before sending them to that website.

What is the most reliable way to do this? I guess PHP can't help since HTTP_REFERER is a client-side variable. Maybe JavaScript then? Is there a lightweight library for that?

Comment: you can't its browser set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the referrer in JavaScript, but not set it.

You could send them to an in between page, say in PHP, that could set the referrer however, and then forward them on.

[Here is the process on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428762/hide-referrer-on-click/11249553#11249553) & [a walkthrough on using that SO link.](http://deftmarketer.com/hide-referer-php-script/)

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, but aren't there any workarounds? There are so many sites that are doing just that...

Comment: I updated my answer to have a solution provided here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 2):

a js-only method:

```
location.href="data:text/html,"+
  encodeURIComponent("<script>location.href='http://yahoo.com/'<\/script>");
```

even if the code did leave a ref, it would be to the dataURL, not your site.

Comment: Seems to be working, can you provide any backing documentation on this?

Comment: Hm, I found this. Seems like this _would_ be reliable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238890/convert-html-to-datatext-html-link-using-javascript I havent seen anyone use data-URI like this before, but it is quite clever!

Comment: backing documentation? its a simple single command, so i'm not sure what you're looking for. i just made it up after thinking about  it; the protocol change will mask the orig site's domain...

Comment: Oh I just meant maybe something showing using this method for clearing the referer, and maybe pitfalls.

Comment: yeah, i don't know that it's an actual  "thing", but it should work to do what you want ;)

Comment: Love this, very clever.

Answer (score 0):

The only fool-proof way is to have some sort of transition page between your source and destination.

For example: `example.com/var/product/1234` => `example.com/redirector/google.com` => `google.com`

This way the destination site would only receive the transition page's link.

If you want to completely hide the fact that users are coming from your site, you need to have the transition page hosted on another domain. The [anonym.to](http://anonym.to/) website offers just such a service. However since this is a free, 3rd party service, you may want to host your own instead to guarantee availability and prevent any possible logging of requests. The implementation would be about 3 lines of PHP code.